# PhpDesigner 8 looses focus when using autocomplete

Tags: phpdesigner

My phpDesigner 8.1 looses focus when I use any autocomplete. It is really annoying because i have to click into the window each time I use autocomplete. Does somebody know how to fix this? I tried the protable version and the setup. Both have the same behaviour.

Comment: I think you should report this issue to the developers of the application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could finally fix it on my own. Teamviewer was the problem.

See this [phpDesigner Changelog](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner_changelog.php).

> phpDesigner 7
>   phpDesigner 7 version 7.2.5 -- 1. March 2011
>
> [...]
>
> Fixed. The code completion loses focus. This is a problem caused by Teamviewer. When Teamviewer is running it puts a small button near windows options buttons, you need to click that button and cancel Teamviewer for phpDesigner.exe and phpDesigner 7 will work fine again. The same applies to Actual Windows Manager.

**EDIT:** Seems like mpsoftware.dk removed their changelog. Here is the old page: [phpDesigner Chagnelog (New Link)](http://web.archive.org/web/20130815154226/http://mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner_changelog.php)

Comment: I tried to debug the input events on that window. Teamviewer catches all inputs (for checking if I click on their icon) and if I didnt click on their icon they send the same window message again (to emulate the keypress). Php Designer didnt like that.

Comment: @DanielBrunner thank you for this answer. all i thought I'm the only one having this problem and i wouldn't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed answer BUT to fix this just go to Teamviewer Option > Advanced > Show advanced options > QuickConnect Button > Configure > Untick Show QuickConnect Button

Comment: I've been battling with this issue for 6 months now and was about to go through the tedious process of changing IDE. It didn't happen for me on Windows 7, but started with Windows 10! Thanks very much :-)